# jQuery Undefined in SPFx

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, spfx

I have been reading various articles including this one [use jquery functions within spfx webpart](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/206441/use-jquery-functions-within-spfx-webpart/206443) but I can't seem to get jQuery to work with my SPFx webpart.

My first attempt was putting the loading in the global scope:

```
  public constructor() {
    super();
    SPComponentLoader.loadCss('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
    SPComponentLoader.loadCss('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');

    SPComponentLoader.loadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js', { globalExportsName: 'jQuery' }).then((jQuery: any): void => {
      SPComponentLoader.loadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js', { globalExportsName: 'jQuery' }).then((): void => {
      });
    });
  }
```

Despite being in the constructor, the code above results in an error within my render function (**jQuery not defined**):

```
  public render(): void {
        this.domElement.innerHTML = /* etc...*/

      const webpart: ContactFormSimpleWebPartWebPart = this;

      // assign handlers
      jQuery('#btn-submit-contact-form-simple').on('click', function() {
        webpart.SubmitContactFormSimple();
      });

      // assign vars
      this.Category = jQuery('#sel-category');
      this.Message = jQuery('#txt-message');
      this.ErrorContainer = jQuery('#div-contact-form-simple-errors');
  }
```

Next, I've tried adding the typings for version 2 (which, I understand, is the highest version SPFx supports):

> npm install @types/jquery@2.0.48 --save-dev

```
  "externals": {
    "jquery": {
      "path": "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js",
      "globalName": "jQuery"
    }
  },
```

The above results in numerous compile errors similar to the following:

> ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

I even tried adding it directly to the render, which doesn't result in any errors, except that nothing happens!  No resulting HTML is shown."):

```
  public render(): void {

      SPComponentLoader.loadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js', { globalExportsName: 'jQuery' }).then((jQuery: any): void => {
      SPComponentLoader.loadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js', { globalExportsName: 'jQuery' }).then((): void => {
          this.domElement.innerHTML = /* etc...*/

          const webpart: ContactFormSimpleWebPartWebPart = this;

          // assign handlers
          jQuery('#btn-submit-contact-form-simple').on('click', function() {
            webpart.SubmitContactFormSimple();
          });

          // assign vars
          this.Category = jQuery('#sel-category');
          this.Message = jQuery('#txt-message');
          this.ErrorContainer = jQuery('#div-contact-form-simple-errors');
      });
    });
  }
```

I've even tried adding it on the init:

```
  protected onInit(): Promise<void> {
    SPComponentLoader.loadCss('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
    SPComponentLoader.loadCss('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');

    SPComponentLoader.loadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js', { globalExportsName: 'jQuery' }).then((jQuery: any): void => {
      SPComponentLoader.loadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js', { globalExportsName: 'jQuery' }).then((): void => {
      });
    });

    return Promise.resolve(undefined);
  }
```

What else can I try to be able to use jQuery in my SPFx webpart?

**Edit:** When I try to `import * as jQuery from 'jQuery'` I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Looks like you are loading jQuery and bootstrap into your project with the same `globalExportName`

Comment: Could you post a link to a github repo to pull down?

Comment: Yes, that is how I copied it from some online resource I found.  My repository is local.  Is there any code I can provide you as clarification?  The project is quite the same as the default yeoman template excepting the changes I've made in my class which extends BaseClientSideWebPart.

Comment: have you tried to do an `import * as jQuery from 'jQuery'` yet? I found an article online that has a different setup with the externals. Instead of using path and global name just put `"jquery": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"`  substitute the path you want to use for the js file though. https://blog.mastykarz.nl/sharepoint-framework-client-side-web-parts-jquery-plugins-cdn/

Comment: I have also tried the alternative in the config.json you recommend, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.  I updated the question with a screenshot of what happens when I import from 'jQuery'.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oops!  When I do `import * as jQuery from 'jquery';` (lower-case jquery) it works!  However, I have a question - instead of using the local package, I would prefer to use the SPComponentLoader as I can also load bootstrap 4 which only works with higher levels of jquery.  Is my approach correct - using the constructor?  Or, how else can I use bootstrap 4 with SPFx is there any way?

Comment: Nevermind :) It works with bootstrap 4 and jquery 3.  I read online that it didn't but that appears to be false.  Thanks for your great help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried to do an `import * as jQuery from 'jQuery'` yet? I found an article online that has a different setup with the externals. Instead of using path and global name just put "jquery": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" substitute the path you want to use for the js file though.

https://blog.mastykarz.nl/sharepoint-framework-client-side-web-parts-jquery-plugins-cdn/

Comment: Thanks, again.  For posterity, the answer for me was (with a small q) `import * as jQuery from 'jquery';`

Comment: For me, I was missing the jquery "externals" entry in config.json